# How to delete or substitute certain values of a dataset

Tags: r, contains

My dataset is the following:

```
structure(list(Data = c("01/2023 (p)", "12/2022 (p)", "11/2022 (p)", 
"10/2022", "09/2022"), index = c("99,1", "96,2", "110,2", "105,4", 
"108,0")), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"
), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x000001f72620e040>)
```

How can I delete `(p)` in column `Data`, so I can transform its format to date?

Comment: Take a look at `gsub()`

Comment: As you are using data.table, in your case you could do something like `DT[, Data := sub(" (p)", "", Data, fixed = TRUE)]`

Comment: Is there any option to apply this code to the whole data frame? So I don't have to specify the columns

Answer (score 1):

The parenthesis `(` is a special character in regular expressions so you need to escape it with `\`. The problem is that `\` also needs to be escaped so you end up with `\\(`.

```r
dat <- structure(list(Data = c("01/2023 (p)", "12/2022 (p)", "11/2022 (p)", 
                               "10/2022", "09/2022"), index = c("99,1", "96,2", "110,2", "105,4", 
                                                                "108,0")), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"))

dat
#>          Data index
#> 1 01/2023 (p)  99,1
#> 2 12/2022 (p)  96,2
#> 3 11/2022 (p) 110,2
#> 4     10/2022 105,4
#> 5     09/2022 108,0

dat$Data <- gsub(" \\(p\\)", "", dat$Data)
dat
#>      Data index
#> 1 01/2023  99,1
#> 2 12/2022  96,2
#> 3 11/2022 110,2
#> 4 10/2022 105,4
#> 5 09/2022 108,0
```

<sup>Created on 2023-03-14 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: `sub(" (p)", "", dat$Data, fixed=TRUE)` might do it also.

Answer (score 0):

A more straightforward to convert your string to date is to use `lubridate::parse_date_time`, where you can specify the type of formats to parse:

```r
lubridate::parse_date_time(df$Data, orders = c("%m/%Y (p)", "%m/%Y"))
#[1] "2023-01-01 UTC" "2022-12-01 UTC" "2022-11-01 UTC" "2022-10-01 UTC" "2022-09-01 UTC"
```

Comment: How can I assign it to the dataset?

Comment: With `<-`, like `df$Data <- lubridate::parse_date_time(df$Data, orders = c("%m/%Y (p)", "%m/%Y"))`